# Products of the o-Toluidine oxidation with glucose oxidase and peroxidase

Tags: water, biochemistry

Could anybody describe which product is formed in the following reaction (o-Toluidine oxidation)?

$$\ce{H2O2 + o-Toluidine_{uncolored} - Peroxidase -> H2O + 1/2 O2 + o-Toluidine\; Oxidate_{colored}} $$

**Note**: Hydrogen peroxide is one of the products of glucose oxidation to glucolactone by glucose oxydase.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @Amaterasu Not really. If I remember correctly, this was/is a method for the  photometric determination of glucose in blood.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha ah, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The product most likely is 2-methylnitrobenzene (**3**), which means that the amino group ($\ce{-NH2}$) in o-toluidine (**1**) is oxidized to a nitro group ($\ce{-NO2}$). The oxidation proceeds via 2-methylnitrosobenzene (**2**).

[image: toluidine oxidation]

The formation of 2-methylnitrobenzene can be detected photometrically at $\lambda$ = 400 nm, where the aniline does not absorb.